# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyLDAvis' in anaconda spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, lda

I am using anaconda sypder and installed `pyLDAvis` module using command:

```
conda install -c ehremo pyldavis
```

Even after successful installation it shows error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyLDAvis'" in anaconda spyder
```

while using command `import pyLDAvis`. Please help.

Comment: Have you installed your module in a specific anaconda environment? if so check if your python spyder kernel points to the correct environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go, this uses anaconda for instillation

```
conda install -c memex pyldavis
```

That fixed it on my end and can use pyLDAvis

Comment: This is not in spyder, but in a terminal or cmd. so write that line in a CMD and install this into your anaconda environment.

Answer (score 9):

```
conda install -c memex pyldavis
```

This command didn't work for me

But this one worked

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyldavis
```

Answer (score 4):

I had same problems with this module

First try:

`conda update anaconda`

if you use jupyter notebook and you had "No module named.."
try:

`pip install --upgrade pip`

`pip install --upgrade jupyter notebook`

a next

`pip install pyLDAvis`

I completed these steps and I could use jupter console to check

`import pyLDAvis`

`pyLDAvis.__version__`

Comment: If you are using Colab: `pip install pyLDAvis`

Answer (score 1):

On Jupyter notebook, following worked for me

```
!python -m pip install -U pyLDAvis
```

Alternatively, run Anaconda prompt as administrator and execute the following

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>conda install -c conda-forge pyLDAvis
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in Anaconda prompt:

conda install -c conda-forge pyLDAvis

then type y in the following section:

The following packages will be UPDATED:

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Comment: Hi, this answer is same as Ajinkya's answer. Try to look for recent questions to answer where community needs you.