# No module named pyLDAvis

Tags: python, import, gensim, pyldavis

I can't import pyLDAvis.

It is installed but for some reason, I can not import it.

I tried

```
conda update anaconda

pip install --upgrade pip

pip install --upgrade jupyter notebook

pip install pyLDAvis
```

Installing pyLDAvis returns the message 'requirement already satisfied'. So I tried uninstalling and reinstalled the package but still doesn't work. This never happened with any other packages.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyLDAvis' in anaconda spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946003/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyldavis-in-anaconda-spyder)

Answer (score 65):

The pyLDAvis gensim name changed.  When I use *gensim_models* rather than *gensim* the interactive viz works.

The 'gensim_models' name is in the latest commit to [bmabey's repo](https://github.com/bmabey/pyLDAvis#:%7E:text=pyLDAvis%20is%20designed%20to%20help,an%20interactive%20web%2Dbased%20visualization.&text=Note%3A%20LDA%20stands%20for%20latent%20Dirichlet%20allocation.).

```
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.gensim_models as gensimvis
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()

# feed the LDA model into the pyLDAvis instance
lda_viz = gensimvis.prepare(ldamodel, corpus, dictionary)
```

Comment: Modifying name from gensim to 'gensim_models' works for me. Thankyou

Comment: I get an error, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyLDAvis.gensim_models'

Comment: #Creating Topic Distance Visualization 
import pyLDAvis.gensim_models as gensimvis
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
gensimvis.prepare(base_model,corpus,id2word)

This is my code. I am using pyLDAvis 3.3.1

Answer (score 15):

Following code worked for me and I'm using Google Colaboratory.

```
!pip install pyLDAvis

import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.gensim_models

pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
vis = pyLDAvis.gensim_models.prepare(ldamodel, doc_term_matrix, dictionary)
vis
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are working in jupyter notebook (python vs3.3.0)

> "the No module named ‘pyLDAvis.gensim’"

error can be solved using:

```
import pyLDAvis.gensim_models
```

instead of:

```
import pyLDAvis.gensim
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
!pip install pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.gensim_models
```

This should work.
I faced the same issue and it worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below

```
import pyLDAvis.gensim_models as gensimvis
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
vis = gensimvis.prepare(lda_model, corpus, dictionary)
vis
```

Answer (score 1):

The `pip` installation may not agree with Anaconda. It is better to use `conda` installation.

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyldavis
```

Then it should work fine with Anaconda Python.

Answer (score 0):

Update your pyLDAvis package to the latest version, which includes the `pyLDAvis.gensim_models` module. You can do this by running the command:
`pip install --upgrade pyLDAvis in your terminal`.

Answer (score 0):

The updated solution is:

```
import pyLDAvis
from gensim.models import LdaModel

pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
vis = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(ldamodel, doc_term_matrix, dictionary)
pyLDAvis.display(vis)
```