# Installed updated pyLDAvis but module missing 'pyLDAvis.gensim_models'

Tags: python, pip, pyldavis

I found different links that answers this problem but it does not work

- [No module named pyLDAvis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66759852/no-module-named-pyldavis)

what seems to be the problem? from pip freeze:

```
pyLDAvis==3.3.1
```

from code:

```
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.gensim_models as gensim_vis
```

error:

```
File "my_py.py", line 2, in <module>
import pyLDAvis.gensim_models as gensim_vis
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyLDAvis.gensim_models'
```

Comment: I am also stuck at the same

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in jupyter notebook (python vs3.3.0) "the No module named ‘pyLDAvis.gensim’" error can be solved by using:

```
      import pyLDAvis.gensim_models
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It does fix the problem ... but why do you have to explicitly import it and `import pyLDAvis` is not sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This worked for me:

```
    !pip install pyLDAvis==3.3.1
```

And then do:

```
    import pyLDAvis.gensim_models
```